# PHP: Updating userpicture in session?

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to upadte something in the session?
I got this profile picture changer on the site im working on. 
But when the user uploads the picture and inserts the path to the database, the user picture does not change before the user log's out and in.
Is there any way to maybe update the session info?

Comment: `$_SESSION['key_where_you_store_the_image']= $what_do_you_really_need_to_store_there`?

Comment: I will store the path to an image uploaded by the user. The picture is stored in the users folder. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['key'] = "value";
```

...

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting new path into database, you have to update your session too. If it does not works automatically, do it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible. Just update the session.